# Extracting JSON data to PDF file

Tags: json, ruby, rest, pdf

I am trying to extract the data that I receive from a REST client in a JSON format into a PDF file. I know that I need to format it in columns/sections so first I need to convert to a text format, but is there a way to do that in Ruby? If so, does anyone have an example?

Here is the format of the JSON data that I am getting from the REST API:

```
{"id"=>123456, "documentKey"=>"xyz", "globalId"=>"xyz", "itemType"=>1234,
"project"=>123, "createdDate"=>"2015-02-20T00:11:56.000+0000",
"modifiedDate"=>"2015-02-20T00:11:56.000+0000",
"lastActivityDate"=>"2016-03-02T16:23:52.000+0000",
"createdBy"=>1234, "modifiedBy"=>12342,
"fields"=>{"name"=>"Introduction",
           "globalId"=>"Text",
           "documentKey"=>"Text-2",
           "description"=>"Some introduction"
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn). It does not just 'do' this for you, you will still have to figure out how to properly transform the hierarchical json data into a flat 'text-like' data. You will have to make decisions like, do I want to display timestamps, show empty values, etc.

Here is a very crude example:

```
require 'prawn'
data = {"id"=>123456, "documentKey"=>"xyz", "globalId"=>"xyz", "itemType"=>1234, "project"=>123, "createdDate"=>"2015-02-20T00:11:56.000+0000", "modifiedDate"=>"2015-02-20T00:11:56.000+0000", "lastActivityDate"=>"2016-03-02T16:23:52.000+0000", "createdBy"=>1234, "modifiedBy"=>12342, "fields"=>{"name"=>"Introduction", "globalId"=>"Text", "documentKey"=>"Text-2", "description"=>" Some introduction"}}

Prawn::Document.generate('example.pdf') do
  text "Project: #{data['project']}"
  text "Item Type: #{data['itemType']}"
  text "Description: #{data['fields']['description']}"
end
```

[image]

For anything more advanced I would check the prawn manual.

The other quick option is to create an HTML template and convert that to PDF, and there are multiple gems for this as well such as [Wicked_PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) or [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit)

Comment: Also Chrome (>60) now has [a headless option](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) which includes PDF generation, so that may be an option.

Comment: @whodini9, if I were to use PDFKit, first I need to translate the JSON that I receive into html, how should I be doing that? Appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: @ATrivedi More or less in the same way that I displayed. There is no json to html converter that contextually knows the format of your json or how to handle it. Its going to come down to something like Prawn, or something like: `PDFKit.new("<html><h1>#{data['project'}</h1>...")` as in the PDFKit docs. HTML seems to introduce a completely unnecessary level of complexity in my humble opinion. Those libraries are really for generating PDFs from existing html.

Comment: @whodini9 thank you for the quick reply. Also, if you say HTML adds extra layer of complexity, can I use Prawn to directly transfer from JSON to PDF? Because I tried doing it the way you have it above, but the code does not generate a 'example.pdf'? How do I make sure that it generates a PDF? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure? I have the exact code and it creates an example.pdf in the same folder.

Comment: Never mind, sorry it does create a example.pdf, I did not find it before hand but its in the folder. But, I did have a question, when I tried printing out the description from the data field, it printed the description with a <p> tag. Like this:  <p>An intro to this PRD.</p> So, how do I get rid of the <p> tags in the PDF file?

Comment: See my updated code. Does this still happen? For me the PDF does not have html tags.

Comment: Hnmm thats weird because I have the exact same code and I am getting the html tags